# Why can't TypeScript "as" and null forgiving operator (!) be at the beginning of the next line?

Tags: typescript, syntax, newline, line-breaks

The following code cannot be compiled in TypeScript with or without the parentheses `()`:

```
const foo: string | undefined = undefined;

const a = ("something very long and take all this line"
    as any);

const b = (foo // Could be something very long as well
    !.toString());
```

Interestingly, without the `!.`, `.toString()` or even `?.toString()` would work well on the new line.

Why is this happening? Assuming a code style that has maximum character per line, how do I move these to the new line? I have tried wrapping them in parentheses `()` or put a `\` at the end of the line, none works.

Comment: it works if you put the `as` and `!` respectiviely at the and of the previous line. For the "why"? Probably some part of language specification ...

Comment: Yep, I have just discovered that if I put `!` at the end (then `.` at the beginning of next line), it works. Still looks very... weird to me but I guess I will have to do that for now. I now realize `!` and `.` are two separate operators. In my mind they have always been together as one.